# Create a column of UUIDs in Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, uuid

[Google BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/data-types) doesn't support [UUID](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt) as data type. So, which option is better to store it:

- `STRING`: String with the format 8-4-4-4-12
- `BYTES`: Array of 16 bytes (128 bits)

Comment: What are the factors to decide which is better? Lower cost? Performance? Compatibility with other systems that use UUIDs? Are you asking how to *generate* UUIDs in BigQuery, or just how to store them?

Comment: Thank you. My intention was to pose a generic question to discuss both implementations in different scenarios. In my specific case, I would only care about compatibility, as cost and performance are not bottlenecks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Edit: BigQuery now supports a [function called `GENERATE_UUID`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/uuid_functions#generate_uuid). This returns a `STRING` with 32 hexadecimal digits in five groups separated by hyphens in the form 8-4-4-4-12.

Original content:

Some discussion of the tradeoffs:

## Using `STRING`

- UUIDs are compatible with the representation in other systems, such as if you export to CSV and then want to merge with exports from elsewhere.
- UUIDs are compatible with BigQuery's [probably UUID implementation](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35905496). You will be able to generate UUIDs of this same form using a function (when the feature is implemented).
- If you decide to represent the UUIDs as `BYTES` later, you can potentially convert using a UDF.
- Downside: Comparisons may not be as fast as with `BYTES` depending on the operator, since string comparisons have to take UTF-8 encoding into account. (It sounds like this isn't an issue for you).
- Downside: Storage costs are higher. (It sounds like this isn't an issue for you).

## Using `BYTES`

- UUIDs are stored more compactly; storage is cheaper and comparisons are faster.
- If you decide to represent the UUIDs as `STRING`s later, you can potentially convert them using a UDF.
- Downside: UUIDs are not compatible with other systems after export, and will likely not be compatible with BigQuery's implementation either.

Comment: TLDR: Use STRING as Google implemented GENERATE_UUID that returns STRING type: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/uuid_functions#generate_uuid

Comment: When/where are you supposed to run the `GENERATE_UUID()` statement? I'm assuming in some kind of `ALTER TABLE` statement after the table has already been created, correct?